# I want to use javascript vars in link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I am using follwing javascript. but output is text. I want This Output in Link.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">

  _url = document.location

  _picurl = "danny.jpg"

  _title = "Your Title Here"

  _desc = "Your Description Here"

 _fbshare ="http://fbshare.mobie.in/l"

  document.write( _fbshare + "?" + "site=" + _url + "&Pic=" + _picurl + "&Title=" + _title + "&Ds=" + _desc)

</script>
```

I want use `document.write( _fbshare + "?" + "site=" + _url + "&Pic=" + _picurl + "&Title=" + _title + "&Ds=" + _desc)` in link but no idea.

Comment: semi-colons aren't optional. But what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Is this too simple or do you need to give more informations ?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik — Yes, [they are](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9) (although using semi-colon insertion is considered a bad idea).

Comment: @Quentin: I know they're not **always** mandatory... You're right, but you will unleash hell if you don't use them as they may get wrongly inserted. Hence I rather say they're mandatory. Happens even to average developers not just beginners...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of some messy `document.write` use the cleaner method and select or create the anchor and set it's attributes accordingly.

Also you cannot modify an already existing element via `document.write`, you have to select it from the dom and then manipulate it's attribute.

The correct way would be for example if you have the link already in your html:

```
<a id="link" href=""></a>
```

Your script:

```
var a = document.getElementById("link"); // or another equivalent method
a.innerHTML = 'linktext';
a.href = "#somelink";
```

or if the link does not yet exist:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.innerHTML = 'linktext';
a.href = "#somelink";
// insert into the document
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

[See the example](http://jsfiddle.net/usCFt/)

Comment: I'd replace `document.querySelector("a");` with `document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]`.

Comment: @Blender I always prefer `querySelector[All]` above the other methods except the ID selector. I guess this is just a matter of taste and doesn't really matter for this example.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following element where you want your link to appear:

```
<span id='mySpan'></span>
```

The following code can put your link inside this element:

```
<script language='javascript'>
_url = document.location;    
_picurl = "danny.jpg";    
_title = "Your Title Here";
_desc = "Your Description Here";    
_fbshare ="http://fbshare.mobie.in/l";
_linkTitle = "Link";

document.getElementById('mySpan').innerHTML="<a href='"+_fbshare + "?" + "site=" + _url + "&Pic=" + _picurl + "&Title=" + _title + "&Ds=" + _desc+"'>"+_linkTitle+"</a>";
</script>
```